# count divs with multiple comboboxs and specific selected values

Tags: jquery, combobox, count

Consider the following HTML;

```
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="a" selected>A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b" selected>B</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="a" selected>A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to count the number of div's (with jquery) that have option value 'a' selected AND option value '1' selected

I've tried the follwoing;

```
$('div').find('option[value="a"]:selected option[value="1"]:selected').length
```

I'm looking for a selector that DOES NOT use '.each'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
$('div').has('option[value="a"]:selected').has('option[value="1"]:selected').length;
```

Check that it has both options with the required selections. This basically takes all the divs, then filters out those that don't have an option with `value="a"`, then filters out those that don't have `value="1"`.